# A double written by Java is not recognized by Ruby

Tags: java, ruby

I am using an algorithms written in Java with such an output feature:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("lalala.txt"));

out.writeChars(string_double_copy_B[0] + "/" + string_double_copy_B[1] +  "\t");                                            
out.writeChars(String.valueOf(corrValue));                                      
out.writeChars("\n");
```

`corrValue` is a double.
`string_double_copy_B` is a string array.

After that I try to read a produced file with ruby. I have the following code.

```
input=File.open("lala.txt","r")
genes=[]

input.each_line{|li|

    keys=li.split("\t")
    length=keys.length
    puts(keys[length-1].inspect)

}
```

and I get such an output:

```
"\u00000\u0000.\u00009\u00000\u00000\u00002\u00003\u00003\u00006\u00006\u00001\u‌00005\u00003\u00006\u00000\u00002\u00001\u00005\u0000"
```

Something wring happens when java writes a double into a file. I have tried as well with `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("lala...))`
It shows me the same thing.

How can I fix it? What is then the appropriate way of writing in java in order to get a normal double?

```
kik@kik-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ od -t a -t x1 stemcells09_negative_werte.txt 
0000000 nul   1 nul   0 nul   5 nul   3 nul   _ nul   a nul   t nul   /
         00  31  00  30  00  35  00  33  00  5f  00  61  00  74  00  2f
0000020 nul   R nul   F nul   C nul   2 nul  ht nul   2 nul   0 nul   3
         00  52  00  46  00  43  00  32  00  09  00  32  00  30  00  33
0000040 nul   6 nul   9 nul   6 nul   _ nul   s nul   _ nul   a nul   t
         00  36  00  39  00  36  00  5f  00  73  00  5f  00  61  00  74
0000060 nul   / nul   R nul   F nul   C nul   2 nul  ht nul   0 nul   .
         00  2f  00  52  00  46  00  43  00  32  00  09  00  30  00  2e
0000100 nul   9 nul   0 nul   3 nul   1 nul   6 nul   9 nul   9 nul   6
     00  39  00  30  00  33  00  31  00  36  00  39  00  39  00  36
```

Comment: You are writing as character, and you get character. Nothing wrong with that, you just have to convert it back (though I am sure a method exists for writing numbers directly)

Comment: Let's start by verifying that your file contains the data you expect. Assuming you're on Linux, use `od -t a -t x1 lalala.txt`; edit your post with the first few lines of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You write binary representation of String instead of String itself. Use `Writer` instead to write Strings:

```
Writer out = new FileWriter("lalala.txt");

out.write(string_double_copy_B[0] + "/" + string_double_copy_B[1] +  "\t");                                            
out.write(String.valueOf(corrValue));                                      
out.write("\n");
```

Comment: This is almost the correct solution for the Java side, but it doesn't properly handle character encoding. If the OP is lucky, the encoding will be compatible. A better solution is to use `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(), "UTF-8"))`

Comment: Are you sure you pass new file to your ruby code? Check lala.txt vs lalala.txt